# Populus Unittesting: How to test a contract's fallback function?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, fallback-function, unittesting, populus

How can I test the invocation of the fallback function by an external account of a contract using the [Populus framework](http://populus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

For example, this runs forever:

```
chain.wait.for_receipt(mycontract.transact({'value':10, 'from':accounts[1]}))
```

And these two simply fail:

```
chain.wait.for_receipt(mycontract.transact({'value':10, 'from':accounts[1]})())
chain.wait.for_receipt(mycontract.transact({'value':10, 'from':accounts[1]}).call())
```

I could just use one of `accounts` to send Ether to the contract, but how do I do that in Populus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is straightforward, you can simply use populus' `web3` fixture:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({'value': 10, 
                          'from': accounts[1], 
                          'to': mycontract.address})
```